# How can I safely exit from a non-zero `run` command in a Rails generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are creating a Rails generator to add more functionality when creating new Rails apps. At the moment, we have something like the following.

```
run "bin/yarn add normalize.css"
```

This is fine, but what happens when `bin/yarn` fails for some reason? Right now, the generator shows a warning and continues to do its things.

We would like to capture any failing response from `run` and halt the generation.

From some initial investigation, it looks like `run` does not provide this functionality. Is it even possible with a Rails generator?

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: `run` must be a custom method that you have defined somewhere in your code because [run is not a method for generators according to the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html).